# Need to assist to draw deployment diagram

Tags: uml, diagram

I have a web application that implemented with MVC(Model-View-Controller Pattern).
**I need to assist to draw deployment diagram for this application.**
I think that this has 3 physical components: Web Browser, Web Server & Database Server. 
In my opinion Web Server has 3 components: Presentation Layer, Controller Layer, Model Layer that communicates with Web Server.

I need to help.

Is this idea correct?

Comment: You could tried to use UML Deployment diagram...

Comment: @Ali if you need help then 1st step is to try help yourself. Google search for images of "uml deployment diagram mvc" returns some MANY ready to copy/paste examples. If you read some hundred existing examples you should find some that resembles your case well enough - to get started and refine

Comment: @Ali before reading hundreds of examples you may find useful just 6 carefully selected, see http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html chapter "Deployment Diagrams"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do the task you must first have a solid understanding of **deployment diagram** itself and its abstractions. This diagram shows the distribution of software components over the HW infrastructure.

Its main elements:
- **Nodes** (HW servers, CPUs, devices, routers, etc) and their links (e.g. network)
- **COmponents** (pieces of software as deployed on Nodes) and their dependencies (which components use which other ones).

Back to your question... You say:

> I think that this has 3 physical components: Web Browser, Web Server
>   & Database Server.

Ignoring the "I think part" (you should be sure :)), I assume "physical component" refer to HW nodes - than we have 3 here: Client computer (WEB Browser), WEB Server and DB Server - the last two are separate nodes!

> In my opinion Web Server has 3 components: Presentation Layer,
>   Controller Layer, Model Layer that communicates with Web Server.

Again ignoring "In my opinion" (check it out before modelling, to avoid "crystal ball gazing"). The 3 component should be somehow distributed between 2 Nodes, Presentation and controller probably in WEB server and DB Server on the other node. Dependencies are clear.

YOu have another component "WEB Browser", that runs on the client machine.

Please remove the uncertainties and we can refine this.